# How do I convert a List<Entry> to Map where value is a list using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I convert a `List<Entry>` to `Map<Entry::getKey, List<Entry::getValue>>` using streams in Java 8?

I couldn't come up with a good KeySelector for Collectors.toMap():

```
List<Entry<Integer, String>> list = Arrays.asList(Entry.newEntry(1, "a"), Entry.newEntry(2, "b"), Entry.newEntry(1, "c"));
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

What I want to get: `{'1': ["a", "c"], '2': ["b"]}`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any duplicate keys in your entry `List`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics there are two entries which have their keys as `1`

Comment: @Aominè That appears to be one entry with the key of `1` and the value of `["a", "c"]`.  What I'm talking about would be something like `{'1': ["a", "c"], '1': ["x", "z"] ... }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do so by using the `groupingBy` collector along with `mapping` as the downstream collector:

```
myList.stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), mapping(e -> e.getValue(), toList())));
```

import required:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

---

You can actually accomplish the same result with the `toMap` collector:

```
 myList.stream()
       .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), 
                 v -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(v.getValue())),
              (left, right) -> {left.addAll(right); return left;}));
```

but it's not ideal when you can use the `groupingBy` collector and it's less readable IMO.

Comment: How can I avoid static import? There's an error about lambdas if I write `.collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
                )`

Comment: IDEA loses the type of `e`, it says it's just an `Object`. Actually fixed it by retyping somehow, thanks.